# We would like to make the function which does not forward the exception which has reference permeability dynamically?

Tags: visual-c++

Google translate :

The interpreter is created, an array of bytes into the array in a machine language to cast the enum type and function, I have made an approach to dynamically execute a function, reference Please tell me if the machine-language site.

Babelfish translate:

It is to make the interpreter, but inserting machine language in arrangement at the byte unit, but if it is it makes function dynamically with the approach that it arranges the very the cast, it executes that in functional type through enum, there is a sight of the machine language which becomes reference, please teach.

Original question:

インタプリタを作っているのですが、機械語をバイト単位で配列に入れて
その配列をenumを通して関数型にキャストし、それを実行するというアプローチで関数を動的に作っているのですが、
参考になる機械語のサイトがあれば教えてください。

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369912/is-english-required-on-stackoverflow

Comment: The google translate of this is worthless - reads like my latest power tool instruction booklet, only worse.

Comment: Hey google translate got your comment right! - "This article is written in Japanese."

Comment: 探しているのは機械語によって関数を生成するためのページです。
タグにあるとおり、VisualC++を使っています。

Comment: That's probably because @nanashino99 used Google Translate to create it. In reality (and based on my years of translating), what it actually says is "my hovercraft is full of eels".

Comment: ha ha ... now that's a question I can answer.

Comment: Well, good luck finding a person who can understand Japanese to answer your question. (さて、幸運は、あなたの質問に答えるために、日本を理解することができる人を見つける) says google translate

Comment: added babelfish translation - no better

Comment: Whoops, apparently tagging using Japanese characters doesn't work.

Comment: If he cannot phrase it in English, he will probably not be able to read the English answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a guess - a pure guess:

> You have an array of bytes containing the machine code for a function.  How can you write a cast such that the function can be executed?

In which case, the answer is likely to be:

> In most modern operating systems, the system protects you from converting data into executable code.  The best way to deal with it would be to package the code as a function in a dynamically-loaded (shared) library, and then use the standard calls for the operating system to load that library and execute the function.